# Iphone tab bar control

Tags: iphone, events, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar control and need a method in the view controller of each tab to get called once a tab bar item is selected.

Does anybody know which method gets called?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a UITabBarControllerdelegate and then you have:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

where you retrieve the viewController on which you can call whatever method.

You also get the tabBarController that contains all the viewControllers on which you could iterate to call the method

Answer (score 0):

```
viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: do the respective views appear when you press the tab... if yes then 'viewWillAppear' must be getting called...

Comment: no problem... you've done it on another of my posts too elsewhere. but don't worry about it.